Error while dropping table since it has - in schema name
drop table CG-RSE.ASO_CHANGES_22AUG2024;
drop table CG-RSE.ASO_CHANGES_22AUG2024
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended


drop table CG-RSE.ASO_CHANGES_22AUG2024
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended


You can escapte the name by surrounding it with quotes:
drop table "CG-RSE".ASO_CHANGES_22AUG2024

